# Limit number of cores Dask does not work?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Even though I set up number of cores to be 24, all 120 cores are in use with 100%.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import dask
dask.config.set(pool=ThreadPool(24))

from dask.distribted import Client
client = Client(processes=True, threads_per_worker=1,
                n_workers=24, memory_limit='20GB')
client
```

[image: I set up dask this way]

[image: all cores are in use]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Maybe a library you use also tries to use all cores. If so there probably is a `SOMETHING_NUM_THREADS` environment variable you can set.

Comment: What about share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually telling Dask is, run at most 24 Python functions at a time.  However, those Python functions can do anything they want, including using many threads.

This is particularly common if you are using NumPy with any modern BLAS implementation.  The common solution to this is to set environment variables like

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1  # if you're using OpenBLAS or another OpenMP library
MKL_NUM_THREADS=1  # if you're using MKL
```

But I don't know what your code actually does, so it could be that there is some other way to control threading from within your functions that differs from what is above.

Also the two approaches you've taken apply to different schedulers.  The first applies to the local scheduler.  The second to the distributed scheduler.  That's fine, but default the distributed scheduler will take over, and the first few lines of your example don't have any effect.